# Running command on file(s) in the result of a `find`

Tags: shell, sed, find

I would like to do some changes to multiple files in the hierarchy having the same name (myfile).
Basically I would like to replace the first line of the file by "my new line" and remove the second line. I tried to do it this way:

```bash
find . -name myfile -exec cat {} \; | sed -i -e '1 c my new line' -e '2d'
```

It works at lower level of the hierarchy when the myfile is in the directory where I execute the command but does not work at a higher level.

I have following error messages:

```
sed: no input files
find: ‘cat’ terminated by signal 13
```

How can I do this? 
(I am not very knowledgeable about Unix commands.) 
The point is to redirect the output of the cat to the sed
and modify the same file which has been found.

Comment: Why not just `-exec sed ...`?

Comment: `cat`ing a file's contents to `sed -i` doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you actually mean to pass the file name to `sed` to edit in place?

Comment: Regarding `It works at ...` - no, that code can't possibly work anywhere.

Comment: Actually I thought that the number of the line was needed at each line for sed to be able to delete a specific one (sed -e '2d' file_name to remove the second line). I though cat was doing the job upfront.
I saw in an example online using the cat command :
cat /dir/file | sed -e "s/the_original_line/the_new_line/" > /dir/temp_file
and I though I should do something similar

Comment: (1) Generally, `cat`’ing a file into a pipe is a bad pattern to copy. (2) If you are 100% sure that every existing file has at least two lines, you can say ``sed '1,2 c my new line'``.  But, if you have a file with only one line, then that command (`1,2 c`) will delete the existing line and leave you with an empty file.  But even the command you have (and also my “improved” version) will leave an empty file untouched; they will not insert your new line if there is no pre-existing line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the `cat` command fixes your issue:

```bash
find . -name myfile -exec sed -i -e '1 c my new line' -e '2d' {} \;
```

The `{}` argument in exec is the filename, so it runs the `sed -i` command in place for each of these files.

Comment: It is working much better. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can change lines with sed without the need to call `find`  first:

```
sed -i '1c my new line' **/myfile
```

although you might need to set globstar first (`shopt -s globstar`)